# What is wrong with my for loop - it's not catching the highest grade

Tags: swift, for-loop

I have a for loop (inside a function) that is supposed to output the highest grade in the class. But it's not catching the "A" in the class. Why not?

I also sort of expected my array index to generate an out of range error, but I'm not getting one. Lucky, I guess, though I'm not sure why.

```
struct Student {
   let firstName: String
   let lastName: String
   let grade: String 
}

struct Classroom {
 let nameOfClass: String
 let students: [Student]

 func highGrade(students: [Student]) {
     var x: Int = 0

     for student in students {
        if students[x].grade < students[x + 1].grade {
            print(student.grade)
             x += 1
         }
         else {
             print("Nope")
         }
     }
 } }

let student1 = Student(firstName: "Keith", lastName: "Grimes", grade: "F")
let student2 = Student(firstName: "Debbie", lastName: "Grimes", grade: "A")
let student3 = Student(firstName: "Nicholas", lastName: "Grimes", grade: "C")

let class1 = Classroom(nameOfClass: "Swift", students: [student1, student2, student3])

class1.highGrade(students: [student1, student2, student3])
```

I'm trying to find the highest grade in the class out of three students.

Comment: *Debug* your code. Set a breakpoint in that function and single-step through the code. Watch the contents of the variable `x` – it is probably not what you expect.

Comment: You're not even checking entire array. The way you're comparing the grades, if `students[1].grade < students[0].grade`, the index will never increment, and while the loop continues, you will be stuck on comparing `student[0]` and `student[1]`

Comment: You should return an array of students if you consider that more than one student might have the maximum grade    `var highestGrades: [Student] {`
       `var result: [Student]  = []`
        `var highestGrade = "F"`
        `for student in students {`
            `if student.grade < highestGrade {`
                `highestGrade = student.grade`
                `result = [student]`
            `} else if student.grade == highestGrade {`
               `result.append(student)`
           `}`
        `}`
       `return result`
    `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer explicit initializer to sort students on initialization as below,

```
struct Classroom {
    let nameOfClass: String
    let students: [Student]

    init(_ className: String, students: [Student]) {
        self.nameOfClass = className
        self.students = students.sorted(by: { $0.grade < $1.grade })
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let student1 = Student(firstName: "Keith", lastName: "Grimes", grade: "F")
let student2 = Student(firstName: "Debbie", lastName: "Grimes", grade: "A")
let student3 = Student(firstName: "Nicholas", lastName: "Grimes", grade: "C")

let class1 = Classroom("Swift", students: [student1, student2, student3])
print(class1.students.first?.grade)
print(class1.students.first?.firstName)
```

**Output:**

```
Optional("A")
Optional("Debbie")
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem, if you want to find max graded student, use this safety code: `students.max { s0, s1 -> Bool in return s0.grade < s1.grade}`.

```
            struct Student {
        let firstName: String
        let lastName: String
        let grade: String
    }

    struct Classroom {
        let nameOfClass: String
        let students: [Student]

        func highGrade() -> [Student] {
            return self.students.sorted { s0, s1 -> Bool in
                return s0.grade < s1.grade
            }
        }
    }

    let student1 = Student(firstName: "Keith", lastName: "Grimes", grade: "F")
    let student2 = Student(firstName: "Debbie", lastName: "Grimes", grade: "A")
    let student3 = Student(firstName: "Nicholas", lastName: "Grimes", grade: "C")

    let class1 = Classroom(nameOfClass: "Swift", students: [student1, student2, student3])

    let gradedStudents = class1.highGrade()
    print(gradedStudents)
```

Comment: Note that might have more than one student with the maximum grade. This will return only one.

Comment: If i knew that there is needed sorted students by grade, i can easily give correct answer. I have updated in context of asker.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're iterating over students is just incorrect. In the worst case scenario, if `student[1].grade < student[0].grade` you will be stuck comparing the first two students while you iterate over the array.

Try

```
func highGrade(students: [Student]) {
    var bestStudent : Student?

    for student in students 
    {
        if let aStudent = bestStudent 
        {
            if student.grade < aStudent.grade
            {
                bestStudent = student
            }
        } else 
        {
            bestStudent = student
        }
    }
    guard let bestStudent = bestStudent else { return }
    print(bestStudent.grade)
}
```